# Testing for differences bewteen individual z scores (different samples)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-score

I have conducted a survey of risk preferences in a specific province of a given country. There is data of risk preferences of this same country/province from 5 years ago, and I would like to test if there are differences between risk preferences, so a simple test of differences in a before and after fashion.

The issues is that the data from the past is expressed as a z-score at the individual level, basically Z score : ((individual risk preference - mean of the sample (risk)) / standard deviation. We do not have the mean and standard deviation of the sample, just the final z scores in the data base.

For the current data, which we collected  we proceeded to calculate the z scores in a similar fashion, but I am not positive I can compare those to the ones of the past, given that each mean is sample specific.

Is there a test I can conduct to check for differences using these z scores? or do I have to try to get the mean and standard deviation of the sample from 2012  and conduct tests with the raw risk preferences at the individual level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes sorry about the typo, corrected